# What different on kotlin with object and companion in memory use?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory

I have two solution to store constants :

```
object A {
    class B {
        companion object {
            const val VALUE_ONE = 1
        }
    }

    object C {
        const val VALUE_TWO = 2
    }
}
```

I don't know what different with this two in runtime memory use.

Which is better memory performance on Android?

Which uses less memory in Android life cycle?

I think VALUE_TWO is better then VALUE_ONE

Let me know what you think.

Comment: There's really no need to worry about these things. Memory issues come from much bigger things than a single constant or class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the memory difference between these two approaches is usually small and unlikely to significantly impact memory usage or Android performance. Choose the approach that makes your code more organized and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Both will be treated as `static final int`.
Companion object and object in Kotlin are singleton. so if you decompile your code, it'd look like this.

```kotlin
class B {
    public static final int VALUE_ONE = 1;

    @NotNull
    public static final Companion Companion = new Companion();

    public static final class Companion {
         private Companion() { }
    }
}

public static final class C {
    public static final int VALUE_TWO = 2;

    @NotNull
    public static final C INSTANCE;

    private C() { }

    static {
        INSTANCE = new C();
    }
}
```